# Why is this not accessible outside the function?

Tags: c

I have no idea why I'm getting segmentation fault when I try to access `all_tracks_ptr[1].tracks[1].tracks_title` outside the function. This is just a small piece of my total code. How do I fix this? or What is a better way of returning the information I scanned from the files into main?

```
album *pharse_album(FILE *album_file,int *number_of_albums){
    int number_of_album,number_of_tracks,number_of_charaters;
    int i,j;
    char dummy_space;

    fscanf(album_file,"%d", &number_of_album);

    *number_of_albums = number_of_album;

    album *all_albums_p = (album *)malloc(sizeof(album)*number_of_album);
    for(j=0;j<number_of_album;j++){
        fscanf(album_file,"%d", &all_albums_p[j].num_tracks);
            tracks *all_tracks_p = (tracks*)malloc(sizeof(tracks)*all_albums_p[j].num_tracks);
        for(i=0;i<all_albums_p[j].num_tracks;i++){
            fscanf(album_file,"%d", &number_of_charaters);
            all_albums_p[j].tracks = (tracks *)malloc(sizeof(tracks)*all_albums_p[j].num_tracks);
            all_albums_p[j].tracks[i].tracks_title = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(number_of_charaters+6));
            fscanf(album_file," ",dummy_space);
            fscanf(album_file, "%[^\n]s", all_albums_p[j].tracks[i].tracks_title);

            printf("%s\n",all_albums_p[j].tracks[i].tracks_title);
        }
      }
      return all_albums_p;
    }


    main(){

        all_tracks_ptr = pharse_album(album_file,number_of_albums);

        for(i=0; i < *number_of_albums ;i++){
            printf("%d : %d\n",i,all_tracks_ptr[i].num_tracks);
            printf("%s",all_tracks_ptr[1].tracks[1].tracks_title);

        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't show us where all_tracks_ptr gets assigned

Comment: Indeed, if the code for `main` is accurate, it is not assigned.   OP, please post the smallest possible piece of code which, when run, demonstrates your problem - that is, please make a complete example of your problem, and then remove all the parts of the code that are not necessary to demonstrate the problem.   (In fact, in doing this, you might identify the bug yourself, it's a useful technique).

Comment: Just added the part there all_track_ptr is assign.

Comment: What does this line do: all_tracks_ptr = all_tracks_ptr(); ?

Comment: opps sorry missed paste. Corrected now.

Comment: if all_tracks_ptr is a ptr to the first element of an array made of struct tracks_, then the member tracks does not exist...? — ok seen the result is what pharse_album func returs... though I think the name of the variable could be a bit misleading

Comment: So how can I pass back tracks as well?

Comment: we asked for minimal working code; your func pharse_album() uses an undeclared unitialized var j: `all_albums_p[j].tracks = malloc(sizeof(tracks)*5);` ... missing a for loop...?

Comment: Please check the result of `fscanf` for failure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the code never makes a `struct tracks_`, which I assume is what an `all_tracks_ptr` should be pointing to?

Comment: Yes. I would like to return all_albums_p.tracks.tracks_title. So that way I can print the album_ and its tracks_.

Comment: I'll wait till you post the code. Is the return value from `pharse_album()` intended to be an array of album? If it is, how will the caller of the function know how many album struct's are in the array?